# In MHD, why is the magnetic force aquared?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

I'm trying to understand how the following equation:

$-\nabla P + j\ \times\ B + pg = 0 $

Reduces to:

$\frac{P_0}{L_0}=\frac{B_0^2}{\mu_0 \rho_0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the magnetic field magnitude squared?

(I rephrased your question as I assume this is what you were asking)

In [MHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics), one generally ignores the [displacement current density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) such that:
$$
\mathbf{j} = \frac{ 1 }{ \mu_{o} } \nabla \times \mathbf{B} \tag{0}
$$
then we have the following:
$$
\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} = \frac{ 1 }{ \mu_{o} } \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{B} \right) \times \mathbf{B} \tag{1}
$$
From [vector calculus identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities), we can show that:
$$
\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} = \frac{ 1 }{ \mu_{o} } \left[ \left( \mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{B} - \frac{1}{2} \nabla \left( \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{B} \right) \right] = \frac{ \left( \mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{B} }{ \mu_{o} } - \nabla \left( \frac{ B^{2} }{ 2 \ \mu_{o} } \right)  \tag{2}
$$

> Where do these terms come from?

(I rephrased your question as I assume this is what you were asking)

The factor of $L_{o}^{-1}$ comes from the assumption that $\nabla \ Q \propto L^{-1} \ Q$, where $L^{-1}$ is some characteristic scale length and $Q$ is the relevant parameter (i.e., you assume all $Q$ are proportional to an exponential function of height/altitude).  In your particular problem, it seems the notation is $L_{o}$, which I am guessing represents an [atmospheric scale height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height) or some reference altitude at which the mass density is $rho_{o}$.